# GET 1ST LETTER AFTER SPACE IN TEXT BOX

Tags: space, letter-spacing

I have 1000's of record in a database and I have one field as name and other as code
now i want to replace all code with every 1st letter after space from name for example
in name field

Manoj Sir Madan   then replace code will be "MSM"

Suraj Bhai Bhanu  then replace code will be "SBB"

Aayush Deepak Bhanu  then replace code will be "ADB"

1st letter from start then every 1st letter after space
I do not have code nor did I find any

Can any one help me with this

Comment: Which programming language you use?
I can help if you use Python, JavaScript, or Java.

Comment: I use foxpro for dos I Know its very old but still I have a database which is very large thats the reason. and I donot want to convert it in other file